# lightning-input checkbox - getting checked rows when submitted

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, checkbox

When submit button is clicked, how do I know which rows have been checked?

.html

```
        <template for:each={products.data} for:item="product">
            <a
                href="#"
                key={product.Id}
                data-contact-id={product.Id}
                
            >
                <lightning-layout>
                    <lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-input
                            label={product.Product2.Name}
                            type="checkbox"
                            >
                        </lightning-input>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </a>
        </template>
        <lightning-button label="Submit" title="Next" onclick={handleSubmit} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getProductist from '@salesforce/apex/GetProducts.getProductList';

export default class showProducts extends LightningElement {
    @track record;
    @track error;
    @track checked = false;
    @track disabled = true;
    @wire(getProductist) products;

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('event-----j--', JSON.stringify(event));
        console.log('event-------', event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let selected = [
  ...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')
  ].filter((input) => input.checked)
  .map((input) => input.closest('[data-contact-id]').dataset.contactId);
```

Where:

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')
```

Finds your input values, then:

```
[...arrayLikeObject]
```

Converts an array-like object, such as the results from querySelectorAll, into a true Array, then:

```
.filter((input) => input.checked)
```

Filters out unchecked boxes; only checked boxes remain. After that:

```
  .map((input) => input.closest('[data-contact-id]').dataset.contactId);
```

Maps the original inputs into the contactId value you set on the `a` element (`.closest` finds the nearest ancestor element that meets the CSS filter, in this case, the `data-contact-id` attribute).

Comment: exactly what I needed! Also thank you for the breakdown explanation. Really appreciated